# Deserializing item from SOAP service in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I've been banging away at it for hours, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to deserialize this SOAP in WCF:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:getItemResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.MyApp.com/API">
      <return>
        <item guid="{EED02630-B742-461C-2F3C-227A2898D40A}">
          <name>Widget1</name>
          <description>A pretty cool thing</description>
          <product>3</product>
          <tag1>asdf</tag1>
          <tag2>fdsa</tag2>
        </item>
      </return>
    </ns:getItemResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my service client implementation:

```cs
[ServiceContract( Namespace = "http://www.MyApp.com/API" )]
public interface ISvc
{
    [OperationContract( Action = "getItem" )]
    GetItemResponse GetItem( GetItemByNameRequest request );
}

[MessageContract( IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "getItem" )]
public class GetItemByNameRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember( Name = "name", Namespace = "" )]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract( IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "getItemResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://www.MyApp.com/API" )]
public class GetItemResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember( Name = "return", Namespace = "" )]
    public Item[ ] Return { get; set; }
}

[DataContract( Name = "item" )]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string product { get; set; }
}
```

I want to ignore tag1 and tag2, so I haven't included them in my datacontract (there are about 30 extra tags I don't care about in the SOAP response that I removed for brevity).
When I call the GetItem method, the value of GetItemResponse.Return is null, for the response given above.
What am I missing?

I'll be happy enough to get the elements of the item to deserialize, but if I can also get the attributes out, I'll be even happier.

I've tried changing the Return property of the GetItemResponse class to XmlNode[] and I get a single-node array back from that, so I have a feeling I'm really close.

An auto-generated service reference is out of the question, as the service is HUGE and causes our assembly to be over 10MB larger and pay a >1 minute startup penalty.  It also exposes the result as `object[]` rather than as `Item[]`, which isn't terribly useful, since I can't cast `object[]` to `Item[]` (actual underlying type seems to be `XmlNode[]`).

Here's the XSD for the response object:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.MyApp.com/API" xmlns:myapi="http://www.MyApp.com/API" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xsd:complexType name="Response" abstract="true">
    <xsd:attribute name="sequence" type="xsd:unsignedLong" use="optional" />
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name='Item'>
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs='0'>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs='1' name='name' minOccurs='0' type='xsd:string'></xsd:element>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs='1' name='description' minOccurs='0' type='xsd:string'></xsd:element>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs='1' name='product' minOccurs='0' type='xsd:int'></xsd:element>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs='1' name='tag1' minOccurs='0' type='xsd:string'></xsd:element>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs='1' name='tag2' minOccurs='0' type='xsd:string'></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name='getItemResponse' type='myapi:GetItemRes'></xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name='GetItemRes'>
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base='myapi:Response'>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name='return'>
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name='item' type='myapi:Item'></xsd:element>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Why do you try to do it manually, adding a *Service Reference* to your client is not working?

Comment: I only want a small subset of the functions exposed, as there are hundreds, and using an auto-generated service reference causes a huge application startup delay.

Comment: @dodexahedron: try it with a service reference first. See if you can get that to work before trying things manually. And service references do not cause any startup delay, unless you're using an ASP.NET Web Site "project". Since those are compiled at runtime, there could be a delay. Yet another reason to never use them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, the service reference works fine, it's just that, because of the size of it, the generated service reference causes the assembly size to increase by over 10MB and the application takes well over a minute to start, even if I have visual studio pre-compile the XmlSerializers. I'm doing it manually so I can have a clean, lean, and portable dll to drop into any consuming application.

Comment: Also, the auto-generated service reference exposes the result as object[] , rather than as Item[].  This array can't be casted to Item[] - only to XmlNode[].  I want to work with Items, not XmlNodes.

Comment: Are you sure that the application startup time is due to the service references? Have you profiled your application? Where is the startup spending its time?

Comment: Yes. When the service reference is there, whether it is used or not, the application takes forever to load. When it is not there, the application starts instantly.

Comment: Can you take the service reference code and then just remove all the types and operations you don't require? It seems to me you've already burned hours on this - is it just a case of programmers pride? http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/the_seven_sins_of_programmers

Comment: Please see the updated question and my responses to previous inquiries about the service reference code. The types it returns are farther away from what I want than my own code gets me with a partial line modification.  The best the service reference can give me as a return type is `object[]`, and it doesn't seem this XML should be impossible to deserialize into `Item[]` or `Item` instead.  To use the service reference code still requires a lot of manual coding to convert XmlNode[] into `Item`, so it's going to take time no matter what.